# My Antlr4 Grammar doesn't understand math expressions

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4, lexer

i have this Grammar

```
grammar Arith;

exp : LPAREN exp RPAREN
    | fun
    | num
    | exp (OP exp)+
    ;

num : LPAREN num RPAREN 
    | LESS num 
    | INT 
    | INT 'b'
    | '0x' INT 
    ;

fun : LPAREN fun RPAREN
    | LESS fun 
    | FUN_TXT LPAREN exp RPAREN
    | 'pow' LPAREN exp ',' exp RPAREN
    ;

INT : ('0'..'9')+ ;

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;

FUN_TXT : 'log' | 'acos' | 'asin' | 'atan' | 'cos' | 'abs' | 'sin' | 'sqrt' | 'tan' ;

OP : ADD | LESS | MUL | DIV | MOD ;

ADD : '+' ;
LESS : '-' ;
MUL : '*' ;
DIV: '/' ;
MOD: '%' ;
WS : [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;
```

I try to insert *sin(-1)* but the lexer said me "no viable alternative at input '-'".

I think that program translate it in "**exp** -> **exp (OP exp)+**" instead of "**exp** -> **fun(num)** -> **fun(LESS num)**"

Could someone help me to understand what i've forget and how change my rules in the right way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would simplify your rules for num and fun

```
num : INT 
    | INT 'b'
    | '0x' INT 
    ;

fun : FUN_TXT LPAREN exp RPAREN
    | 'pow' LPAREN exp ',' exp RPAREN
    ;
```

Brackets and minuses are handled by the exp rule.

You also need to separate the ADD and SUB from the multiplicative operators to get precedence right. The [calculator](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/calculator) example for the Antlr grammars uses

```
expression 
    : multiplyingExpression ((PLUS|MINUS) multiplyingExpression)*
    ;

multiplyingExpression  
    : powExpression ((TIMES|DIV) powExpression)*
    ;

powExpression
    : atom (POW expression)?
    ;

atom 
    : scientific
    | variable
    | LPAREN expression RPAREN
    | func
    ;

scientific
    : number (E number)?
    ;

func
    : funcname LPAREN expression RPAREN
    ;
```

I would be inclined to start from that.

Comment: I didn't have seen this example before, it's perfect. Thanks